# How to select specified page index in grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a one grid view, on row command event i am redirecting on another page with query string that contains a current page index of grid view.

On redirected page i have a back button, when i click on this button i want redirect previous page with specified page index

**For example:**

suppose i am on my page-1  and current page index of grid view is 15 and on row command event  i am redirecting on page-2.when click "back button" it must be redirected to page-1 with page index of 15 of grid view.

My code is as below:

**Code of page that contains grid view (Page-1)**

```
if (e.CommandName.ToLower() == "application")
{
  Response.Redirect("view-msme-em-1-with-print.aspx?pageIndex=" + i , false);
}
```

**Code of page that contains Button(Page-2)**

```
protected void iBtnBack_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{      
  Response.Redirect("searchMSMEApplication.aspx?pageIndex=" + Request.QueryString["pageIndex"].ToString() );       
}
```

**Code on page load event that contains gird view(page-1)**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  fillGridOnLoad(); // it fills a grid view  with data
  grvEm2Application.PageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["pageIndex"].ToString());

}
```

when i click a "Back" on "page-2" it is redirecting to page-1 but page index is not as i set. is any thing missing?

Comment: try setting it in PreRender, or in the grid databound event.

Comment: Try setting `PageIndex` _before_ calling `Databind()` on gridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   grvEm2Application.PageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["pageIndex"].ToString());  
   fillGridOnLoad(); // it fills a grid view  with data
}
```

Just need to set PageIndex before data bind